# Retrieve a list of json objects using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-json

I need to retrieve a list of json objects from mysql database, parse it using volley and populate a listview with it. I'm new to php and volley. Here's how I'm trying.

JSON:

```
{"result":[{"id":"3133482000","name":"John Doe","class":"3A","parent":"admin@gmail.com","status":"0","stopid":"6","busno":"0"},{"id":"0","name":"","class":"","parent":"","status":"0","stopid":"0","busno":"0"},{"id":"334","name":"sam","class":"3a","parent":"","status":"0","stopid":"2","busno":"0"}]}
```

Android:

```
 JSONArray sts;
public static final String STUDENT_URL = "http://www.smartlbus.esy.es/getAllStudents.php";
        students=new ArrayList<Student>();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(STUDENT_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                sts = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                                for (int i = 0; i < sts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jo = sts.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Student s=new Student();
                                    Toast.makeText(StudentDetails.this,jo.getString(STUDENT_NAME),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    s.setId(jo.getString(STUDENT_ID));
                                    s.setName(jo.getString(STUDENT_NAME));
                                    s.setClassNo(jo.getString(STUDENT_CLASS));
                                    s.setBusno(jo.getString(STUDENT_BUS));
                                    s.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(jo.getString(STUDENT_STATUS)));
                                    s.setStopid(jo.getString(STUDENT_STOP));
                                    students.add(s);
                                }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });


                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(StudentDetails.this,students));
```

Please help me out. In case this doesn't meet the standards here, please comment and let me know. I'll take it down.

Comment: Try to use GSON library for the parsing Json

Comment: your url not returning any json response

Comment: I've fixed the url. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to ease your development.

Create your Java POJO Class:

```
public class StudentList {
    List<Student> results;
    // setter

    public static class Student {
          String name;
          String id;
          String status;
          String class;
          String stopid;
          String busno;
        // getter
    }
}
```

Then parse them using GSON in the `onResponse()` method.
I'd suggest to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make network calls.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
StudentList list = gson.fromJson(response);
// populate to ListView using list.getResults()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this & also check your URL. Your url not returning any json response.

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,STUDENT_URL ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                                Log.d("TAG","response :"+response);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                sts = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                                for (int i = 0; i < sts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jo = sts.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Student s=new Student();
                                    Log.d("TAG","Name :"+jo.getString(STUDENT_NAME));
                                   // Toast.makeText(StudentDetails.this,jo.getString(STUDENT_NAME),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    s.setId(jo.getString(STUDENT_ID));
                                    s.setName(jo.getString(STUDENT_NAME));
                                    s.setClassNo(jo.getString(STUDENT_CLASS));
                                    s.setBusno(jo.getString(STUDENT_BUS));
                                    s.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(jo.getString(STUDENT_STATUS)));
                                    s.setStopid(jo.getString(STUDENT_STOP));
                                    students.add(s);
                                }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I've fixed the problem with the url. Code still doesn't work.